Preventing FutureBuilders from rebuilding when reordering them in a reorderable list
Here is sample code using SliverReorderableList:
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SliverReorderableList(
    itemCount: widget.items.length,
    onReorder: onReorder,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = widget.items[index];
      return ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener(
        key: ValueKey(item.id),
        index: index,
        child: Material(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: item.future,
            builder: /* handle all resolved (success & error) and loading states */
          )
        )
      );
    }
  );
}

The FutureBuilders rebuild when dragging is started and ended, causing a split-second flash between the loading and resolved states. How do I resolve this?
Edit: Some failed attempts at a solution:

Moving item.future to a local variable.

Removing FutureBuilder and managing the item.future in a separate widget.


...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SliverReorderableList(
    itemCount: widget.items.length,
    onReorder: onReorder,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = widget.items[index];
      return ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener(
        key: ValueKey(item.id),
        index: index,
        child: Material(
          child: ItemWidget(item: item),
        )
      );
    }
  );
}
...

class _ItemWidgetState extends State<ItemWidget> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  Object? _error;
  Item? _item;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.item.future.then(/* handle success */).catchError(/* handle error */);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // handle all three cases
  }
}


Refactor to not use FutureBuilder, or set 'item.futureas a local variable (this will not callitem.futre` every time the order is changed)

@pmatatias both options also unfortunately don't work
